# mySQL select records based on a dynamic list

Tags: mysql

If I want to pull some records from the database based on a list of unique IDs, what options do I have?

1. run my list ID by ID then and pull data from database with `SELECT`. That would create too many queries, not efficient.
2. create a random table and load the list to the table then use `JOIN` to pull the data. Have to keep creating and deleting temp tables. Not preferable with a dynamic list.
3. option 3: ?

Comment: Are you running the query from a programming langauge? You should be able to construct `WHERE id IN (...)` dynamically from the list.

Comment: Where do the dynamic IDs come from?

Comment: the dynamic ID list is an external file in .txt  or .csv format

Comment: How are you getting it into the MySQL query?

Comment: Is it a one time manual task or is it part of an application?

Comment: By creating a temp table then load using LOAD DATA INFILE at worst. Not sure if there are better ways out there that I am not aware of.

Comment: It is part of an application.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, your approach is better than my first two options. It might eat up the server memory but for now I will use your method.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
SELECT* from myTable WHERE id IN('val1','val3','val3',...);
```

But if you are creating application by using a language , you can create a methode wich can take a `List` in arguments like this:

```
Public void GetDatasById(List<int> list)
{
  // browse your list to make your request (add list elements to your request);
  // execute request 
}
```

Comment: I think this is better approach than my other two options. I can loop through the list and plug it into the query. Thanks

Comment: okay good job. you can accept answer if has been helpfull for you.